# i want to get live stream from an ip cam.. and after that i want pictures from that live stream....in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Imports AForge.Video

Imports AForge.Video.VFW

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim Stream As AForge.Video.MJPEGStream = New AForge.Video.MJPEGStream("http://192.168.1.250/mjpeg.cgi")
        Stream.Login = ("admin")
        Stream.Password = ("admin")
        Stream.Start()

        Dim st As String = ""

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

this is what i have done so far....to get stream started...
know i want know.
 how can i show this stream in picture box? and how to get images from this stream.

Answer (score 0):

The MJEGStream includes events. Declare your `Stream` object on class level as

```
Private WithEvents Stream As AForge.Video.MJPEGStream
```

Then add an event handler to the `MJPEGStream.NewFrame` event with a sub like

```
Private Sub Handle_NewFrame(sender as Object, e as AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs)
   Picturebox1.Image = e.Frame
End Sub
```

Start the stream like you have done in your code.
Don't forget to initialize the Source object.

```
Source = New AForge.Video.MJPEGStream("http://192.168.1.250/mjpeg.cgi")
```

The eventargs variable contains the new frame as an image that you can then display in a picturebox.
It's been a while since I have worked with AForge, but it should be ok.